# Getting IntentFilter data in MvvmCross

Tags: android, mvvmcross

What is the recommended way of handling an activity that gets started by the OS when using an IntentFilter (in my case its when an email attachment is opened) in MvvmCross so I can get the content URL / path in my view model or app start up code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Activity is started by direct Intent then the only place to get hold of that is in the started Activity - eg in `OnCreate`.

If you need to route that information into the ViewModel, then you can use the `ViewModel` member of the MvxActivity to do that (after a cast). Alternatively, with a little effort you can create your Intent so its packaged bundle looks like a normal Mvx ShowViewModel bundle - take a look at how MvvmCross navigates internally using Intent in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Views/MvxAndroidViewsContainer.cs